# libc - standard IO - how its used

Tags: c, ubuntu, stdio, libc

I wonder how the libc.so.6 is handled in memory when a program includes it . I understand its a dynamic lib file and only stored once but I was really surprised how huge this file is.

This syntax directs the stream to myoutput.txt

```
objdump -d libc.so.6 &> /home/john/myoutput.txt
```

I opened it - well its over 18 MB in size and over 300 000 rows.

So - is all of this loaded into ram when a program uses it or just pieces?

Comment: How large is the original file? That's of more interest.

Comment: Well, it is mapped into your address space if used by your program or one of its shared libraries (recursively). Also, its initialization will create a process-private copy of its modified data. But most pages will only be paged in when needed. BTW: It's used by just about all programs running, so the impact of its static size is negligible, as they can and do share all non-modified parts. And naturally, `objdump` might result in orders of magnitude bigger or smaller output than its input anyway.

Comment: @Deduplicator - ok didnt think of that - that virtual mem. taking care of it. A lot of pages may be "sleeping" in the swap-file (not occypying RAM)

Comment: Or even never making it to the swap-page, as there never was any reason to load them from the file at all.